# How do I remove a value from a list, and remove a value in the same position from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have two lists:

> x=[1,0,0,3,2,5,6,0,4,2]
>
> y=[e,r,g,d,e,w,t,y,t,r]

I want to remove all the zeros from the "x" list, and all values correspond to the position of the zeros from the "y" list, such that in the end:

> x=[1,3,2,5,6,4,2]
>
> y=[e,d,e,w,t,t,r]

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]==0:
        del x[i]
        del y[i]
return x
return y
```

However, I realized that as the element in the i-th index position gets deleted, the range changes. Is there a better loop or method I can implement.

Comment: What about keeping a list of the indices you need to delete, and then deleting them afterwards (so that you can loop over the indices to delete, instead of looping over an array where you're changing the size)? Personally I'd just use two list comps: `x = [a for a in x if x != 0]` and the same for `y`.

Comment: Do you need x and y to be edited in-place, or can you just make new lists?

Comment: Thanks everyone! You are all awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you delete an element from a list, all the later indices get shifted backwards by 1 so that there's no gap left by what you deleted. The earlier indices, however, remain untouched; so the simple fix is to iterate over the indices backwards.

```py
def remove_zeros(x, y):
    for i in reversed(range(len(x))):
        if x[i] == 0:
            del x[i]
            del y[i]
    return x, y
```

Note that if you want to return two results, you have to return them as a tuple; the second `return` statement won't be reached otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting, you can construct new lists:

```py
x = [1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 5, 6, 0, 4, 2]

y = 'e,r,g,d,e,w,t,y,t,r'.split(',')

x, y = zip(*[
    (xe, ye)
    for xe, ye in zip(x, y)
    if xe != 0
])

print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

aha, I spent a super long time trying to figure this out when I needed it. Glad you dont have to go through it.

```
def list_del(inp,poss):
'''delete items at indexes given in the list poss from list inp'''
try:
    assert(isinstance(inp,list))
except AssertionError:
    raise(AssertionError('input has to be a list, if numpy, using np.delete'))
inpu = inp

pos = 0
for i in list(sorted(poss)):
    del inpu[i-pos]
    pos += 1
return inpu
```

example:

```
list_del([0,1,2,3,4],[0,2,-1])
```

returns

```
[1, 2]
```

In your case:

```
for i in list(x):
    if i == 0:
        deleting.append(i)
list_del(x,deleting)
list_del(y,deleting)
```

Comment: This code solves a quite different problem. For a start, your two input lists aren't the same length.

Comment: @kaya3 the second input is the positions of the items you want to delete.

Comment: Yes, that is a different problem to what this question is asking.

Comment: @kaya3 added his case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line with a list comprehension:

```
result = [[x[i], y[i]] for i in range(len(x)) if x[i] != 0]
```

Then you have a list of the pairs, which you can quickly get back into your original format with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
resultX = np.array(result)[:, 0]
resultY = np.array(result)[:, 1]
```

Comment: Not quite; `result[0]` is `[1, 'e']`, and `result[1]` is `[3, 'd']`, and `result` has a length of 7.

Comment: Good point, I've edited with a quick conversion to OP's original format using numpy