# Deleting corresponding elements of different arrays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.7, once elements have been deleted from an array based on certain conditions, is there a way to delete elements from a different array with the same indices as those removed from the first?

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep track of the indices.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how I could determine the indices of the elements which have been deleted?

Comment: You should add some code to your question, @CosmicCoder123 showing what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Start by taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Then provide a [mcve].

Comment: @pault A **minimal reproducible** example is only relevant when the programmer encountered an error. What is the shortest and easiest to read piece of code, which follows the same skeleton of the real code, and which produces the same error. If the question asker is not asking about an error, bad output, or unhandled exception, then there is no such thing as a **minimal reproducible example** of code which produces the same error.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon you're talking about a very literal interpretation of the MRE. In this context, the OP should provide some small sample input lists. *"These are my inputs ..."* as well as what the desired output should be. Without those, anyone answering is making an assumption on what is being asked, which may or may not be correct (but is IMO of very little use for future readers). This question almost certainly has a duplicate and an example would help narrow down which duplicate should be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a value from a list, and remove a value in the same position from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808523/how-do-i-remove-a-value-from-a-list-and-remove-a-value-in-the-same-position-fro)

Answer (score 0):

The following code deletes elements from array `a1` and then deletes elements in array `a2` having the same index.

```
import array

# we will delete all values strictly greater than 10

a1 = array.array('d', [1, 34, 8, 19, 6, 27, 9])
a2 = [
    "apple",        # KEEP
    "banana",       # delete
    "kiwi",         # KEEP
    "grape",        # delete
    "strawberry",   # KEEP
    "boysenberry",  # delete
    "jackfruit"     # KEEP
]
a1_pruned = list()
a2_pruned = list()

deleted_idxs = list()

for idx in range(len(a1)):
    if a1[idx] > 10:
        a1_pruned.append(a1[idx])
        deleted_idxs.append(idx)

for idx in range(len(a2)):
    if idx not in deleted_idxs:
        a2_pruned.append(a2[idx])

print(a2_pruned)
# ['apple', 'kiwi', 'strawberry', 'jackfruit']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do this somewhat generically:

```
def filter_seqs(pred, *sequences):
     """ Filter all sequences based on the results 
     of applying `pred` to the first sequence. 

     >>> def is_odd(i):  
     ...    return i % 2 == 1
     >>> a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     >>> a2 = list('abcde')

     >>> filter_seqs(is_odd, a1, a2)
     ([1, 3, 5], ['a', 'c', 'e'])
     """
     # TODO: replace sequences[0] with list in case it is a single-pass iterator.
     keep = [pred(elem) for elem in sequences[0]]
     return tuple([elem for keep, elem in zip(keep, seq) if keep] 
                  for seq in sequences)
```

Note that the predicate is used to *retain* elements when true, following the convention of `filter` in the standard library.

This can be used ergonomically with tuple unpacking:

```
>>> a1_filtered, a2_filtered = filter_seqs(is_odd, a1, a2)
>>> a1_filtered 
[1, 3, 5]
>>> a2_filtered
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it by preserving the index of the element.
You can use enumerate to get the index.

```
list1 = list('ABCDEF')
list2 = list('abcdef')
for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    # some random condtion
    if val == 'C':
        del list1[i]
        del list2[i]

print list1 //['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F']
print list2 //['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to delete elements from a list while iterating over it. The behaviour is often not what you expect; this code gives incorrect results e.g. when `list1 = list('ABCCCAB')`, for example.

Comment: You are right, I was more focused on giving enumerate example..